# Alamofire requests in foreach loop

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I have an array with strings

```
let languages = ["en", "fr", "es"]
let type = ["cat", "dog"]
```

and I want to get all data in foreach loop with Alamofire 4.8

```
languages.forEach {
   Alamofire.request(Endpoints.langList, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Langs.self, from: response.data!)
                    completionHandler(.success(result!))
                case let .failure(error):
                    completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
type.forEach {
       Alamofire.request(Endpoints.typeList, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Types.self, from: response.data!)
                        completionHandler(.success(result!))
                    case let .failure(error):
                        completionHandler(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
```

and I'm getting errors

> finished with error - code: -1001 
>   HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])

and all requests starts twice. 
I realized that when I remove `forEach` loop all works without any errors and multiply requests.

I've tried using `Alamofire.SessionManager` and `DispatchQueue` but it didn't help me.

How can I avoid Alamofire multiply requests inside forEach loops?

Comment: I am not sure about forEach loop, but you can try using recursive function that will only call Alamofire.request on completion of the previous ones

Comment: How many requests are you creating at once?

Comment: @JonShier one for each loop iteration

Comment: Well yes, but how many total? If you create too many, later enqueued requests may timeout before they're issued by Alamofire's underlying `URLSession`.

Comment: @JonShier I created 6 requests. I have similar data set. Three languages and two breeds